# Render Lightning Runtime for Flows in a Visualforce Page and get variable value from URL

Tags: visualforce, lightning-aura-components, visual-workflow, lightning-out

I'd like to launch my flow in lightning run time in a visualforce page and pass a variable to the flow. I previously used a formula URL in classic that appended recordid= Contact.Id to the URL which the flow automatically understood. With Lightning Out I need to pass the ID a different way.  I am not trying to get the record id of the current page because the URL is sent in an email and is opened externally on a site.

Here's my visualforce page:

```
<apex:page showheader="false" sidebar="false">

    <apex:includeLightning />

    <div id="flowContainer" />

    <script>

        var recordId = "{!$CurrentPage.parameters.recordid}";

        $Lightning.use("c:MyLightningApp", function() {

            $Lightning.createComponent(

                "c:MyLightningApp",

                { recordId : recordId },

                "flowContainer",

                function(cmp) {}

            );

        });

    </script>

</apex:page>
```

Here's my aura application:

```
<aura:application access="GLOBAL" extends="ltng:outApp" implements="ltng:allowGuestAccess">

    <aura:attribute name="recordId" type="String" />

    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}" />

    <lightning:flow aura:id="flowData" onstatuschange="{!c.handleStatusChange}" />

</aura:application>
```

Here's my aura application controller:

```
({

    doInit : function(component, event, helper) {

        var recordId = component.get("v.recordId");

        var flow = component.find("flowData");

        var inputVariables = [

            {

                name : "recordId",

                type : "String",

                value : recordId

            }

        ];

        flow.startFlow("jrsl_Unsubscribe_Link", inputVariables);

    },

    handleStatusChange : function (component, event) {

        if(event.getParam("status") === "FINISHED") {

            var urlEvent = $A.get("e.force:navigateToURL");

            urlEvent.setParams({

                "url": "/apex/jrsl_ul_UnsubscribeFinish"

            });

            urlEvent.fire();

        }

    }

})
```

The flow/visualforce page/component is launched with a link like this: https://avenue-q.my.salesforce-sites.com/Unsubscribe?recordId=0038c0000AIzGtpAAF

Comment: What do you mean by "With Lightning Out I need to pass the ID a different way"?

Comment: I have a formula field with a URL that launches the visualforce page and the recordId is passed as a variable appended to the URL. so it looks like https://avenue-q.my.salesforce-sites.com/Unsubscribe?recordId=0038c00003IzGtpAAF.   I'm using lightning run time/Lightning Out (i'm not sure what the difference is) and just adding the record ID at the end of the URL does nothing.

Comment: How are you passing that url parameter into the your LWC?

Comment: Can you Edit your question to include the VF page

Comment: I have edited it to include everything i have. thank you @NickCook